# Exception caught by widgets library ═ Stack Overflow why this only shows when I initializing bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
class _GridViewContentState extends State<GridViewContent> {
  final likeBloc= LikeBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
```

while i comment bloc initialisation it goes away and works. Is there is any convention for initialising bloc pattern

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: i have a like button when click  onPressed: () {
                            likeBloc.mapLikeEvents(LikeEvent(snapshot.data.data.posts[widget.index].id));
                          }

Comment: and then  void mapLikeEvents(LikeEvents events)async{
    if(events is LikeEvent){
      ObjectFactory().repository.likePost(events);
    }
    else
      return;
  }   then I get Stack overflow error

Comment: I mean, can you edit the post with a stack trace or add more details about the exception you're getting?

Comment: no it return only this much ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Stack Overflow
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: if i press one more time it will changes to another one ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'mapLikeEvents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: mapLikeEvents(Instance of 'LikeEvent')
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: well i called a likebloc function inside of a StreamBuilder<UserProfileResponse>( ..... is it this is the reason? while I call userBloc from it no error occurs

Comment: did you initialize bloc?